# Java - Reading a file and loading in HashMap - How to reduce time?

Tags: java, hashmap, inputstream, bufferedreader, fileinputstream

I'm reading files of sizes around 20 MB with around 500,000 records in it. I'm loading the records into a HashMap with a particular field as key and another field as the value. This Map's Key-values are used in the subsequent process.

The time to simply read the file is negligible. But, parsing the field and load into HashMap seems to take hours. The code looks somewhat likes this,

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 102400);
if (br != null) {
    for (String record; (record = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(record);

        map.put(sb.substring(findStartIndex(fieldName1),findEndIndex(fieldName1)), sb.substring(findStartIndex(fieldName2),findEndIndex(fieldName2)));

    }
}
```

where findStartIndex() and findEndIndex() are methods to parse an record format xml and find the start and end indexes of the field.

I need to repeat this process for a bunch of files.
Suggest me someway to reduce the runtime. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I implemented the findStartindex and findEndindex as below,

Input is xml with field names and index values. I used SaxParser, getters and setters for each.. found the values of start and end.

Comment: How long does it actually take?

Comment: I would suggest to use an SQL database, if the file is meant for storing data.

Comment: How do you implement findStartIndex and findEndIndex? 20 MB/500000 record should not take this long.

Comment: I'm running it.. Crossed an hour.. Previously tried with some more parsing line codes and took almost 1 hour for 100,000 records.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's rather long.  I think nhahtdh is on the right track-- we'll need to see more code.  Also the fields `fieldName1` and `fieldName2`, how do they get set?

Comment: @nhahtdh :I implemented the findStartindex and findEndindex as below,

Input is xml with field names and index values. I used SaxParser, getters and setters for each.. found the values of start and end.

Comment: @markspace I'm passing the fieldnames like "PIN_CODE", "FIRST_NAME"..

Comment: cant you just implement the parser on the file itself instead on the StringBuilder?

Comment: The above mentioned code took 22 mins.. Not an hour.. with 500k reocrds.. With few more parsings it takes hours..

Comment: You need to do some basic profiling to find out what is slow.  However, a brief look seems suggest several problems to me: 1) It is meaningless to use StringBuilder here.  You are creating unnecessary objects. 2) You can preallocate the map to be capable to store number of records you need, so it save time in resizing. 3) The most suspcious part is your `findStartIndex` and `findEndIndex`.  You mentioned you use SAX in it? Why can't you parse the XML to a proper object and manipulate it? Parsing multiple time for each "index" is not a good idea to me.

Comment: @eriuzo : could u pl elaborate?

Comment: how do you pass the `StringBuilder` (or the `String`) to `findStartIndex` / `findEndIndex` ? Can you show us some more code? I am pretty sure, that finding the start and the endpoint of a substring can be made much faster. E.g. once you know where the substring starts it is easier to find the end - because you don't have to search the whole string

Comment: im not familiar with sax, but in android i can use xmlpullparser to take an inputstream and directly parse from it.. like XmlPullParser x = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser(); x.setInputStream(in); then after this line i do my parsing.

Comment: Do you parse the files only once? Also I don't suggest sql. And you can achieve better result using one thread to read files and several threads to parse them.

Comment: I was advised to use SaxParser.. So created java object and and retrieve the value from the objects after SaxParsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read millions of lines a second with a `BufferedReader`. The time is undoubtedly going in your unshown XML parsing. It seems you aren't using a proper parser but instead you're apparently just doing string searching on the XML, starting from the beginning of the string both times, which is quadratic, or else parsing each line as XML four times, which is worse. Don't do that. Use XPath to find your fields, it's a lot quicker, or a properly implemented SAX parser listener.

And I don't see any good reason for creating a new `StringBuilder` each line when you already have the line itself.

NB `br` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it.

Comment: yeah, `String` would be a better choice rather than `StringBuilder`

Comment: Thanks.. ll change it as you mentioned.. and ll tell the timings :).. thanks again

Comment: I just removed the parsing for each record. instead used one time parse and used the values. gave an output of 500k records in less than a second. Hope, will be more efficient, if implement ur complete suggestion. Thanks. Thanks a lot..

Comment: If i want to substring multiple fields from a record and need to concatenate them, then creating StringBuilder is the right option or not? Like some more parsing and concatenations in the above for loop.

Comment: If concatenating or delteing/adding chars to string, it's better to use `StringBuilder`. For substring search both have the same efficiency I think